# Oracle Apex Data automatic load from excel

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

everyone, I have created a simple report app showing some data using **Oracle Apex** and I want to make it get Data from a **server(FTP)** through an Excel file and fill its tables automatically whenever I change the excel file, is it possible and if it is, how it can be done, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether the way you said is possible or not.Just a suggestion,

- Create the Report in Oracle Apex based on the Database table
- Create a DB Procedure to  insert the data into DB table from the Excel file
- Create and Schedule a DB JOB which calls the DB procedure, to check the FTP frequently and load file into the table. So Users can see the updated data.